# Flink Inner Join Missing records and adding duplicates

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are running a flink application on AWS Kinesis Analytics.

We are using kafka as our source and sink and event time as our water mark generation. We have a window of 5 seconds. We are performing an inner join using a common field.

Kakfa topics have 12 partitions and flink have 3 way parallelism.

**Issues observed** : We are seeing for some window we are missing records. Records should join based on the event-time but not joining and for other windows we are seeing duplicate records.

**sample records**

```
{"empName":"ted","timestamp":"0","uuid":"f2c2e48a44064d0fa8da5a3896e0e42a","empId":"23698"}
{"empName":"ted","timestamp":"1","uuid":"069f2293ad144dd38a79027068593b58","empId":"23145"}
{"empName":"john","timestamp":"2","uuid":"438c1f0b85154bf0b8e4b3ebf75947b6","empId":"23698"}
{"empName":"john","timestamp":"0","uuid":"76d1d21ed92f4a3f8e14a09e9b40a13b","empId":"23145"}
{"empName":"ted","timestamp":"0","uuid":"bbc3bad653aa44c4894d9c4d13685fba","empId":"23698"}
{"empName":"ted","timestamp":"0","uuid":"530871933d1e4443ade447adc091dcbe","empId":"23145"}
{"empName":"ted","timestamp":"1","uuid":"032d7be009cb448bb40fe5c44582cb9c","empId":"23698"}
{"empName":"john","timestamp":"1","uuid":"e5916821bd4049bab16f4dc62d4b90ea","empId":"23145"}


{"empId":"23698","timestamp":"0","expense":"234"}
{"empId":"23698","timestamp":"0","expense":"34"}
{"empId":"23698","timestamp":"1","expense":"234"}
{"empId":"23145","timestamp":"2","expense":"234"}
{"empId":"23698","timestamp":"2","expense":"234"}
{"empId":"23698","timestamp":"0","expense":"234"}
{"empId":"23145","timestamp":"0","expense":"234"}
{"empId":"23698","timestamp":"0","expense":"34"}
{"empId":"23145","timestamp":"1","expense":"34"}
```

Below is code for your reference.

As you can see here for the two streams there are a lot event timestamp which can repeat. There can be thousands of  employee and empId combinations(in the real data there are many more dimensions) and they are all coming in a single kafka topic.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.WatermarkStrategy;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.AggregateFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.JoinFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.ReduceFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.ValueState;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.ValueStateDescriptor;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeHint;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.functions.KeySelector;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple1;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple3;
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.KeyedStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.co.CoFlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.co.KeyedCoProcessFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.co.RichCoFlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.PrintSinkFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.timestamps.AscendingTimestampExtractor;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.TumblingEventTimeWindows;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.TumblingProcessingTimeWindows;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class Main {

    
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
    // static String TOPIC_IN = "event_hub_all-mt-partitioned";

    static String TOPIC_ONE = "kafka_one_multi";
    static String TOPIC_TWO = "kafka_two_multi";
    static String TOPIC_OUT = "final_join_topic_multi";
    static String BOOTSTRAP_SERVER = "localhost:9092";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Producer<String> emp = new Producer<String>(BOOTSTRAP_SERVER, StringSerializer.class.getName());

        Producer<String> dept = new Producer<String>(BOOTSTRAP_SERVER, StringSerializer.class.getName());

        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        env.setParallelism(1);

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", BOOTSTRAP_SERVER);
        props.put("client.id", "flink-example1");

        FlinkKafkaConsumer<Employee> kafkaConsumerOne = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(TOPIC_ONE, new EmployeeSchema(),
                props);
        
        
        LOG.info("Coming to main function");
        
        //Commenting event timestamp for watermark generation!!

        var empDebugStream = kafkaConsumerOne.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
                WatermarkStrategy.<Employee>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                        .withTimestampAssigner((employee, timestamp) -> employee.getTimestamp().getTime())
                        .withIdleness(Duration.ofSeconds(1)));

        // for allowing Flink to handle late elements

        kafkaConsumerOne.setStartFromLatest();

        FlinkKafkaConsumer<EmployeeExpense> kafkaConsumerTwo = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(TOPIC_TWO,
                new DepartmentSchema(), props);
        
        
        //Commenting event timestamp for watermark generation!!

        kafkaConsumerTwo.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
                WatermarkStrategy.<EmployeeExpense>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                        .withTimestampAssigner((employeeExpense, timestamp) -> employeeExpense.getTimestamp().getTime())
                        .withIdleness(Duration.ofSeconds(1)));

        kafkaConsumerTwo.setStartFromLatest();

//      EventSerializationSchema<EmployeeWithExpenseAggregationStats> employeeWithExpenseAggregationSerializationSchema = new EventSerializationSchema<EmployeeWithExpenseAggregationStats>(
//              TOPIC_OUT);

        EventSerializationSchema<EmployeeWithExpense> employeeWithExpenseSerializationSchema = new EventSerializationSchema<EmployeeWithExpense>(
                TOPIC_OUT);

//      FlinkKafkaProducer<EmployeeWithExpenseAggregationStats> sink = new FlinkKafkaProducer<EmployeeWithExpenseAggregationStats>(
//              TOPIC_OUT,
//              employeeWithExpenseAggregationSerializationSchema,props,
//              FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.AT_LEAST_ONCE);

        FlinkKafkaProducer<EmployeeWithExpense> sink = new FlinkKafkaProducer<EmployeeWithExpense>(TOPIC_OUT,
                employeeWithExpenseSerializationSchema, props, FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.AT_LEAST_ONCE);

        DataStream<Employee> empStream = env.addSource(kafkaConsumerOne)
                .transform("debugFilter", empDebugStream.getProducedType(), new StreamWatermarkDebugFilter<>())
                .keyBy(emps -> emps.getEmpId());

        DataStream<EmployeeExpense> expStream = env.addSource(kafkaConsumerTwo).keyBy(exps -> exps.getEmpId());

        // DataStream<EmployeeWithExpense> aggInputStream = empStream.join(expStream)

        empStream.join(expStream).where(new KeySelector<Employee, Tuple1<Integer>>() {
            /**
            * 
            */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Tuple1<Integer> getKey(Employee value) throws Exception {
                return Tuple1.of(value.getEmpId());

            }
        }).equalTo(new KeySelector<EmployeeExpense, Tuple1<Integer>>() {

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Tuple1<Integer> getKey(EmployeeExpense value) throws Exception {
                return Tuple1.of(value.getEmpId());
            }
        }).window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5))).allowedLateness(Time.seconds(15))
                .apply(new JoinFunction<Employee, EmployeeExpense, EmployeeWithExpense>() {

                    /**
                     * 
                     */
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    
                    

                    @Override
                    public EmployeeWithExpense join(Employee first, EmployeeExpense second) throws Exception {
                        return new EmployeeWithExpense(second.getTimestamp(), first.getEmpId(), second.getExpense(),
                                first.getUuid(), LocalDateTime.now()
                                        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'+0000'")));
                    }

                }).addSink(sink);

//      KeyedStream<EmployeeWithExpense, Tuple3<Integer, Integer,Long>> inputKeyedByGWNetAccountProductRTG = aggInputStream
//              .keyBy(new KeySelector<EmployeeWithExpense, Tuple3<Integer, Integer,Long>>() {
//
//                  /**
//                   * 
//                   */
//                  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
//
//                  @Override
//                  public Tuple3<Integer, Integer,Long> getKey(EmployeeWithExpense value) throws Exception {
//                      return Tuple3.of(value.empId, value.expense,Instant.ofEpochMilli(value.timestamp.getTime()).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS).toEpochMilli());
//                  }
//              });
//
//      inputKeyedByGWNetAccountProductRTG.window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(2)))
//              .aggregate(new EmployeeWithExpenseAggregator()).addSink(sink);

        // streamOne.print();

        // streamTwo.print();

//       DataStream<KafkaRecord> streamTwo = env.addSource(kafkaConsumerTwo);
//       
//       streamOne.connect(streamTwo).flatMap(new CoFlatMapFunction<KafkaRecord, KafkaRecord, R>() {
//      })

//
//      // Create Kafka producer from Flink API
//      Properties prodProps = new Properties();
//      prodProps.put("bootstrap.servers", BOOTSTRAP_SERVER);
//
//      FlinkKafkaProducer<KafkaRecord> kafkaProducer = 
//              
//                              new FlinkKafkaProducer<KafkaRecord>(TOPIC_OUT, 
//              
//                                                    ((record, timestamp) -> new ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]>(TOPIC_OUT, record.key.getBytes(), record.value.getBytes())), 
//              
//                                               prodProps, 
//              
//                                     Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE);;
//
//      DataStream<KafkaRecord> stream = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer);
//
//      stream.filter((record) -> record.value != null && !record.value.isEmpty()).keyBy(record -> record.key)
//              .timeWindow(Time.seconds(15)).allowedLateness(Time.milliseconds(500))
//              .reduce(new ReduceFunction<KafkaRecord>() {
//                  /**
//                   * 
//                   */
//                  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
//                  KafkaRecord result = new KafkaRecord();
//                  @Override
//                  public KafkaRecord reduce(KafkaRecord record1, KafkaRecord record2) throws Exception 
//                  {
//                      result.key = "outKey";
//                      
//                           result.value = record1.value + " " + record2.value;
//                      
//                           return result;
//                  }
//              }).addSink(kafkaProducer);

        // produce a number as string every second
        new MessageGenerator(emp, TOPIC_ONE, "EMP").start();

        new MessageGenerator(dept, TOPIC_TWO, "EXP").start();

        // for visual topology of the pipeline. Paste the below output in
        // https://flink.apache.org/visualizer/
        // System.out.println(env.getExecutionPlan());

        // start flink
        try {
            env.execute();
            LOG.debug("Starting flink application!!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

*Questions*

- How do we debug when the window is emitted ?? Is there a way to add
  both the streams to a sink(kafka) and see when the records are
  emitted window wise ?
- Can we put the late arrival records to a sink to check more about them ?
- What is cause of duplicates ?? how do we debug them?

Any help in this direction is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Flink version are you using? I see that you're still using FlinkKafkaConsumer and FlinkKafkaProducer but both are deprecated and replaced by KafkaSource and KafkaSink.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am using 1.13.2 . Can you please help me to print the exact records for each window. That will be really helpful to debug this issue.

Comment: What is `TumblingMomentTimeWindows` doing? The problem could be in there.

Comment: Could https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-18934 explain this?

Comment: @DavidAnderson my apologies that was a typo. I have updated the correct code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DavidAnderson the above mentioned issue is not happening for us. We are seeing records in all the partitions. We are seeing multiple records coming for each milliseconds and they are all out of order.

Comment: `.withIdleness(Duration.ofSeconds(1))` is aggressive. A short hiccough is all it would take for a stream to be marked idle. That seems inconsistent with the 15 seconds of allowed lateness, and is very much at odds with the 5 seconds of bounded out-of-orderness.

Comment: @DavidAnderson the above was the dev code for testing. Below are the production configuration being used. We read the data from both streams using EventTime
below are the configuration for production
forBoundedOutOfOrderness - 10 seconds
withTimestampAssigner - Event Time 
withIdleness - 5 seconds
allowedLatenessSeconds - 10 seconds
tumbling_window_event_time - 10 seconds

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249199/discussion-between-hopeistheonlyweapon-and-david-anderson).

Comment: @DavidAnderson thanks again for your help here. We have created a  git repo with the test case that I described above. Kindly check and let us know please . https://github.com/anikumarar/flink_join_issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you've misunderstood the behavior of an event-time windowed join. Can you provide a simple, complete example showing the inputs provided, the outputs you expect, and the actual results? I've looked at the code, but it's complex, needs infrastructure I don't have in place, and doesn't have tests.